# Make exceptions to the exceptions of gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Git enables one to ignore folders / files.
For instance:

```
folderName
```

Git also enables one to make exceptions.
For instance:

```
!folderName
```

My question is, if it is possible to make exceptions of the exception.
For instance, given the following folder structure:

- sub1

  - subsub1

    - exceptedFolderThatShouldNotBeExcepted
    - exceptedFolder
    - exceptedFile
    - exceptedFile2
  - subsub2
  - subsub3
- sub2
- sub3

It has a folder, `subsub1`, which may contain lots of files that usually are ignored, but should not be ignored.
This is why `!sub\subsub1` is added to gitignore.
But there should be an exception to that: `exceptedFolderThatShouldNotBeExcepted` should be ignored.

Thus, I am looking for an option like`!!exceptedFolderThatShouldNotBeExcepted` that leads to git ignoring just that folder.

The motivation for this is not having to except all the other folders and files (`exceptedFolder`, `exceptedFile`, `exceptedFile2`).

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](/a/44568924/4265352)

Comment: Thanks, this helped.